# Reading from calendars.icloud.com fails recently...why?

Tags: wordpress, icalendar

We are running WordPress, where a very old script reads the URL of an [iCal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_(Apple)) calendar:

```
$webcal = 'http://pXX-calendars.icloud.com/published/2/verylongstring';

if(!$data = file_get_contents($webcal, false, stream_context_create(array('ssl' => array('verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false))))) {
                echo "<!-- could not read calendar -->\n\r";
            }
```

Recently this fails, and I don't know why.

A year ago I have changed the file_get_contents() from

```
file_get_contents($webcal)
```

to

```
file_get_contents($webcal, false, stream_context_create(array('ssl' => array('verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false)))))
```

because reading failed, and after the change it worked again.

We are getting an *502 Bad Gateway Error* when we enter the $webcal URL into the browser.

Maybe Apple has changed something (like authentication or else)?

What happened and how can we solve this?

Comment: Searching on the error I see: "A 502 Bad Gateway Error means that the web server you've connected to is acting as a proxy for relaying information from another server, but it has gotten a bad response from that other server. ... It's possible the server is overloaded or there are network issues between the two servers, and it's just a temporary problem"

Comment: @anmari: Yes, i thought the same, but this "temporary" is going on for many weeks now.

Comment: Try with another test calendar?   I just tried on my icloud (not a mac user) and as long as I replace the unofficial webcal with the official https or http rfc5545 protocol, I could access the ics file.

Comment: I see also you say it is a very old script.  Since the problem is also there just when accessing via browser window, maybe the url is also old?  Check whether there is an equivalent new url?

Comment: the calendars -> caldev URI subdomain change fixed it for me as we.ll.

Answer (score 4):

It is working now, with a different URL that I've tried:

```
$webcal = 'http://pXX-caldav.icloud.com/published/2/verylongstring'
```

instead of

```
$webcal = 'http://pXX-calendars.icloud.com/published/2/verylongstring';
```

Sadly, I have no idea *why* this works now and didn't work with the old URL. Maybe Apple or the customer using this iCal changed something. The pXX-calendars version might have become deprecated, and nobody knew about it...?

Comment: My users were also suddenly unable to add calendars. Thanks a lot for the new URL. I'm now replacing "calendars.icloud.com" with "caldav.icloud.com" before doing CalDAV requests and it seems to be working.

Comment: @mark: Great. Do you have any Idea why the correct URL has changed?

Comment: Nope, sorry! Not sure why this changed. Though I believe that the caldav.icloud.com URLs have been working for a while and the calendars.icloud.com was just an alias.

Comment: It changed because apple decided to change it, and decided to do so in a way that broke existing access. It's just a DNS name, they could easily have added CNAME's to alias the old addresses to the new, but they chose not to and instead opted for silently breaking existing functionality.